# Read / Write .gz file with PHP (method="PUT")

Tags: php, apache, gzip

I have code to read `json` file send to me via `method=PUT` (file.php)

```
<?php
$putdata = fopen( "php://input", "r" );  // to read/write json
$fp = fopen( "myPut.json", "w" );
while ( $data = fread( $putdata, 1024 ) )
     fwrite( $fp, $data );
fclose( $fp );
fclose( $putdata );
?>
```

but I want as well read .gz version of above file i.e `192.168.1.20/example.json.gz`

I tried to handle this like below:

```
<?php

$gz_file = gzopen( "php://input", "rb" );
$fp = fopen( "event.json.gz", "w+b" );
while ( ! feof( $gz_file ) {
  fwrite( $fp, gzread( $gz_file, 2048 ) );
}
fclose( $fp );
gzclose( $putdata );

?>
```

but in wireshark I got :

`12081  89.736965987    192.168.1.30    192.168.1.20    HTTP    484 PUT /test/file.php HTTP/1.1`

`12083  89.737075602    192.168.1.20    192.168.1.30    HTTP    251 HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error`

#### #

I would like to read this `.gz` file and save it. But it would be great If I could read gz file and fwrite it to other file like it happend for 1st example (myPut.json)

It looks like I have some issue with feof/gzread func:

```
[Thu Nov 09 09:34:52.482566 2017] [:error] [pid 14253] [client 192.168.1.65:38302] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test/file.php on line 29
[Thu Nov 09 09:34:52.482570 2017] [:error] [pid 14253] [client 192.168.1.65:38302] PHP Warning:  gzread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test/file.php on line 30
[Thu Nov 09 09:34:52.482575 2017] [:error] [pid 14253] [client 192.168.1.65:38302] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test/file.php on line 29
[Thu Nov 09 09:34:52.482579 2017] [:error] [pid 14253] [client 192.168.1.65:38302] PHP Warning:  gzread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test/file.php on line 30
[Thu Nov 09 09:34:52.482583 2017] [:error] [pid 14253] [client 192.168.1.65:38302] PHP Warning:  feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/test/file.php on line 29
```

Comment: close `)` in `while` : `while ( ! feof( $gz_file ) {`

Comment: OK I add ' )' but still I got Internal Server error / But I see event.json.gz file but size of gz file is 0 ( due to 500 erro I think)

Comment: Issue resolved - It seems that gzopen doesnt work with php://input so I have to save file first with fopen and after that I read file from HDD and remove - long workaround but works